# Bound Mismatch For Generic Types

Tags: java

This might just be of not seeing the forest for the trees, but I have a class like this:

```
class MyClass<T extends Identifiable<?, String> & Displayable> {
    // stuff
}
```

And then another one like this:

```
 class Value<I> implements Displayable, Identifiable<I, String> {
    // other stuff
 }
```

I assumed `MyClass<Value>` would compile, since all instances of `Value` implement both `Displayable` and `Identifiable<?, String>`, but it doesn't:

> Bound mismatch: The type Value is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Identifiable<?,String> & Displayable> of the type MyClass

Even when I don't use the type in the `implements` part I get the same error:

```
 class Value<I> implements Displayable, Identifiable<Long, String> {
    // other stuff
 }
```

Everything works when I change the `Value` class like this:

```
 class Value implements Displayable, Identifiable<Long, String> {
    // other stuff
 }
```

But my question is: Why won't the substitution work for typed `Value` classes?

Comment: With `MyClass<Value>` it is not yet defined what `I` from `Value<I>` should be. `MyClass<Value<Long>> myClass = new MyClass<Value<Long>>()` should compile.

Comment: @Hugo You are right. But no matter what I use for `I`, it will always fullfill the `?` part of the parameter `T`.

Answer (score 1):

> I assumed MyClass would compile

No, but `MyClass<Value<?>>` will compile.

`Value<I>` is a generic type. When you omit the type variable `<I>` you use a raw type. When you use a raw type the type variable `I` of `Value` does not exists and the compiler can not check if `Value implements Identifiable<I, String>` is a valid substitute for `T extends Identifiable<?, String>`. Thus the compiler error.

Comment: I don't think it's about `I`.  He can't check `Value` either, because even if the type `I` is not used in the "implements" section there is the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be a problem somewhere else in your code. I tried what you say doesn't work and got no errors:

```
class Value<I> implements Displayable, Identifiable<I, String> {
    // other stuff
}
```

Perhaps you forgot the `class` keyword in your declaration of `Value`?

Comment: No, the missing `class` key word was a mistake when writing this question.